# Why does it say the length of the array is 1 in this function (C++)?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, sizeof, function-definition

So I'm trying to make a function that gets the length of an array by returning the sizeof the array and sizeof the integer type...

code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int len(int *thing) {
    return sizeof(thing) / sizeof(int);
}

int main() {
    int fard[] = {100, 45, 1, 723, 500};
    cout << len(fard);
}
```

... and when I run the code it just returns with 1

how do I fix this / what did I do wrong.

Comment: `sizeof(thing)` is the size of a pointer, right?  Do you disagree?

Comment: This is an instance of [array to pointer decay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay). `fard` is an `int[5]` array, but when you pass it to `len` it decays to an `int*` that has lost all information about how many elements were contained in `fard`.

Comment: Note that this function already exists (correctly implemented) in the standard C++ library: `std::size(fard)`.

Comment: `thing` is not an array. It's a pointer.

Comment: Remove these headaches; use `std::vector`.

Comment: Replace `len(fard);` with `std::size(fard)` and your problem is solved - with less code, since you can then delete your `len` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function parameter has a pointer type

```
int len(int *thing) {
    return sizeof(thing) / sizeof(int);
}
```

Even if you will rewrite the function like

```
int len(int thing[]) {
    return sizeof(thing) / sizeof(int);
}
```

nevertheless the compiler will adjust the array type of the function parameter to the type pointer to the array element type as written in the first function declaration.

So within the function the expression `sizeof(thing)` yields the size of a pointer. If the size of a pointer is equal to the value of `sizeof( int )` then the function returns 1.

You could write instead

```
template <size_t N>
size_t len(const int ( &thing )[N] ) {
    return N;
}
```

and then

```
cout << len(fard);
```

to get the number of elements in the array `fard`.

Pay attention to that there is already standard C++ function `std::size` declared in the header `<iterator>` in C++ 17.

So you could write

```
#include <iterator>

//...

std::cout << std::size(fard);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `sizeof(thing) / sizeof(int)` is probably equivalent to **4 / 4 == 1**.
Because `thing` is a pointer and pointers have a size of 4 bytes on 32-bit compilers.

Here:

```
len(fard)
```

when you pass `fard`  to the function, it decays to a pointer. This means that it loses its size information. So inside the function `len` you are dividing a single **pointer** by `sizeof(int)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template< std::size_t N >
int len(int (&thing)[N] ) {
    return sizeof(thing) / sizeof(int);
}

int main() {
    int fard[] = {100, 45, 1, 723, 500};
    cout << len(fard);
}
```

Result:

```
Program stdout
5
```

Code: https://godbolt.org/z/qzdbqEYx1

By the way, on x86_64 your original code returns `2 = sizeof(64 bit pointer)/sizeof(32 bit int)`